# Word that's like verbose, except the length of the text IS necessary?

Tags: single-word-requests

Verbose means "using or expressed in more words than are needed." I am looking for a word that means "only able to be expressed in many words." I am trying to explain to a teacher why my assignment is more words than technically allowed (we're supposed to answer in 300-500 words but I simply cannot get my point across in less) but a word like "prolix" for example means "unnecessarily lengthy" and that obviously is the opposite of what I'm going for.

Comment: 1 - When you can't stay under the word limit, you can expect all teachers to show you who's boss and not listen to your struggles. 2 - You could claim you're detailed, thorough, meticulous, and leave no synonym unturned.

Comment: You might insist that your answer is non-prolix, or anti-prolix, that is necessitates the ample verbiage.

Comment: The subject is **complex**.  There is no word that means precisely "inexpressible in few words" or "requiring many words".

Comment: Not an answer, but it sounds like you're trying to give a comprehensive assignment response when the purpose of the exercise is brevity. Maybe a brief answer won't be as informative or accurate, but it would be a better answer to the question you've been given. Perhaps your teacher can advise on how they would suggest it could be done - asking for help always plays better than arguing with the question.

Comment: "Asking for help always plays better than arguing with the question" is excellent. The OP asks for support for being right with a good label, while not following rules,

Comment: *Scholarly*, maybe.

Comment: Why do you think the teacher would limit the assignment to 500 words if it's not possible to explain it that way? Surely they know how complex this is.

Comment: Regarding your question, why do you need a single word? Just say "I don't think it can be explained that succintly." or "I think my answer is as brief as possible."

Comment: What @Barmar said. It's ironic that an OP who's locked into a futile argument with his teacher for using too *many* words should be asking us for a ***single*** word that means "cannot be adequately expressed without using many words". I say if you can't explain something in a few hundred words or less, you don't understand it yourself! :)